# opencv 3.3-there is no load() mehtod in faceRecognizer.class

Tags: java, opencv

Using opencv3.3 with java ,I find there is no `load()` method  in `faceRecognizer.class`，so I can't load the model is saved by `save()` method;In `faceRecognizer.class` ,just has a `read()` method ,it's no any effect.

So,how to load the model is saved by by `save()` method

Comment: Why do you say it has no effect, what are you doing after `faceRecognizer.read("path-to-model");`